# Generate 3D "matrix" with Pandas, based on comparing two dataframes [Python] [Pandas]

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.x

I am working with Python and Pandas.

I have two DataFrames, of the following type:

```
df_C = pd.DataFrame(data=[[-3,-1,-1], [5,3,3], [3,3,1], [-1,-1,-3], [-3,-1,-1], [2,3,1], [1,1,1]], columns=['C1','C2','C3'])

   C1  C2  C3
0  -3  -1  -1
1   5   3   3
2   3   3   1
3  -1  -1  -3
4  -3  -1  -1
5   2   3   1
6   1   1   1


df_F = pd.DataFrame(data=[[-1,1,-1,-1,-1],[1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,-1,1],[1,-1,-1,-1,1],[-1,0,0,-1,-1],[1,1,1,-1,0],[1,1,-1,1,-1]], columns=['F1','F2','F3','F4','F5'])

   F1  F2  F3  F4  F5
0  -1   1  -1  -1  -1
1   1   1   1   1   1
2   1   1   1  -1   1
3   1  -1  -1  -1   1
4  -1   0   0  -1  -1
5   1   1   1  -1   0
6   1   1  -1   1  -1
```

I would like to be able to "cross" these two DataFrames, to generate or one in 3D, as follows:

[image: Matrix 3D]

The new data that is generated must compare the values of the **df_F** with the values of the **df_C**, taking into account the following:

- If both values are positive, generate 1
- If both values are negative, generate 1
- If one value is positive and the other negative, it generates 0
- If any of the values is zero, it generates None (NaN)

***True table***

Comparison of the data **df_C** vs **df_F**

```
df_C vs df_F = 3D
  +       +     1
  +       -     0
  +       0     None
  -       +     0
  -       -     1
  -       0     None
  0       +     None
  0       -     None
  0       0     None
```

You, who are experts in programming, could you please guide me, as I generate this matrix, I compare the values. I wish to do it with Pandas. *I have done it with loops (for) and conditions (if), but it is visually unpleasant* and I think that with Pandas it is more efficient and elegant.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas does not provide a 3D data structure *per se* ([Panel has been deprecated and removed](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.20.0.html?highlight=panel#whatsnew-0200-api-breaking-deprecate-panel)) - however, it is possible to express this kind of data using the *long format* (also known as [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)) with three key columns (or index levels), instead of the *wide format* you are suggesting.

Starting from your definitions, I believe the following achieves your goal:

```
(
    df_C
    # Transform to long format (two columns: former column names under `variable`
    # and corresponding values under `value`) plus the original index.
    .melt(ignore_index=False)
    # Join with the other dataframe, similarly transformed. join() implicitly joins
    # on indexes, so this will generate all combinations of the `variable` column values.
    .join(df_F.melt(ignore_index=False), lsuffix='_C', rsuffix='_F')
    # Make the index a regular column.
    .rename_axis('index')
    .reset_index()
    # Your rules can be expressed by multiplying the two value columns and examining the sign.
    .assign(combined=lambda df: df.value_C * df.value_F)
    .assign(output=lambda df:
        # Uses the Pandas nullable boolean type (three values: True, False, NA).
        pd.Series(pd.NA, index=df.index, dtype='boolean')
        # If combined is positive, both values were non-zero with the same sign.
        .mask(df.combined > 0, True)
        # If combined is negative, both values were non-zero with opposite signs.
        .mask(df.combined < 0, False)
        # If combined is zero, either of the values was zero, and the NA is retained.
    )
    # Remove intermediary values. The first three columns can also be transformed
    # to a MultiIndex.
    [['index', 'variable_C', 'variable_F', 'output']]
)
```

Comment: Jan, thank you very much, Your solution is flawless, with a perfect explanation. Very elegant!